# Generating username using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attending a beginner course and I am very new to programming. I need to know of a function which generates a username using the first letter of someone's name, the first three letters of a person's surname and a 3 digit number without spaces.
So far I have this:

```
full_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
first_letter = full_name[0]
space_index = full_name.find(" ")
three_letters_surname = full_name[space_index + 1:space_index + 4]
number = random.randrange (1,999)
username = (first_letter, three_letters_surname, number)
print = (username)
```

The output I get is from using a name like John Wayne is:

```
"J", "Way", 14
```

What I want to know is how to change my code so I get something like:

```
jway014
```

Comment: Learn more about string formatting. https://pyformat.info

Comment: `username = "".join([first_letter, three_letters_surname, str(number)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 import random
 import sys

 names = input("Please enter your name: ").split(" ")
 if not (len(names) > 1):
     print("Please input your full and last name.")
     sys.exit()
 first_letter = names[0][0]
 three_letters_surname = names[-1][:3]
 number = '{:03d}'.format(random.randrange(1, 999))
 username = (first_letter + three_letters_surname + number)
 print(username)
```

Comment: What if user enters "L Ron Hubbard"? Or just plain old "Bob"?

Comment: Also, what if the random number is < 100?

Comment: @mhawke Nice corrections, just edited to cover those cases, let me know what you think?

Comment: There are still bugs in this answer. What if user entered "A A Milne"?

Comment: @mhawke Fixed by referring to the last index

Comment: Still problems, but there's not really much point in helping you to edit your way to the same answer that I've already posted :)

Comment: @mhawke True, OP asked a simple question from a beginner's POV, I gave a simple answer that solved his issue.

Comment: Yes. That's fine, the OP seemed happy with that. Beginner programmers could benefit from being shown that there often are a  _lot_ of things to consider for an apparently simple task. They can also benefit from having some explanation rather than a code only post.

Answer (score 6):

You might be better off using `split()` to break the user's name into parts and then extracting from there. This will let you check that the user has entered at least a two word name, and you can also handle the case that someone enters one or more middle names or initials:

```
full_name = input("Please enter your name: ").lower().split()
if len(full_name) > 1:
    first_letter = full_name[0][0]
    three_letters_surname = full_name[-1][:3].rjust(3, 'x')
    number = '{:03d}'.format(random.randrange (1,999))
    username = '{}{}{}'.format(first_letter, three_letters_surname, number)
    print(username)
else:
    print('Error. Please enter first name and surname')
    # try again...
```

Should a surname be less than 2 characters long (not uncommon), the name is left padded with `x` characters.

Some examples:

```
Input            Output
John Wayne       jway014
J J Cool         jcoo777
L Ron Hubbard    lron666
Bob Lo           bxlo001
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
import random

full_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
names = full_name.split(" ")
if (len(names) <= 1):
     print("Please input your full name")
     exit() 
first_letter = names[0][0]
three_letters_surname = names[1][0:3]
number = '{:03d}'.format(random.randrange (1,999))
username = "".join([first_letter, three_letters_surname, str(number)])
print(username)
```

Comment: `number` can be less than 100 - which will not produce a 3 digit string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
username = (first_letter, three_letters_surname, number)
```

With this:

```
username = '{}{}{:03d}'.format(first_letter.lower(),
                               three_letters_surname.lower(),
                               number)
```

Answer (score 0):

import random
import sys

```
 names = input("Mobin: ").split(" ")
 if not (len(names) > 1):
     print("Pour Nowrouz .")
     sys.exit()
 first_letter = names[m][0]
 three_letters_surname = names[our][:3]
 number = 7'{:03d}'.format(random.randrange(1, 999))
 username = (first_letter + three_letters_surname + number)
 print(username)
```